# How to properly mock simple-git library in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to write Jest tests for my NestJS Application that uses the simple-git library. I want to mock the return value of `simpleGit()` so that I can test the module's behavior without actually running Git commands.

Here's the relevant code in my module:

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';

function myFunction() {
  const git = simpleGit();
  git.checkout('my-branch');
}
```

And here's the Jest test spec file

```
import myFunction from './my-module';
import simpleGit, { SimpleGit } from 'simple-git';

jest.mock('simple-git', () => {
  const mGit = {
    init: jest.fn(),
    checkout: jest.fn(),
    addConfig: jest.fn(),
    fetch: jest.fn(),
    pull: jest.fn(),
    checkIsRepo: jest.fn(),
  };
  const mSimpleGit = jest.fn(() => mGit);
  return {
    default: mSimpleGit,
    SimpleGit: mSimpleGit,
  };
});

describe('myFunction', () => {
  it('should call checkout with the correct branch', () => {
    myFunction();
    expect(simpleGit().checkout).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my-branch');
  });
});
```

This actually calls the actual `checkout` function from simple git instead of my Mock, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How can I properly mock the `simple-git` library in my Jest tests?

The expected behaviour should be the test should call the mocked `checkout` function.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and Jest's [automocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) feature instead of specifying an explicit module factory to create the mock objects.

E.g.

`my-module.ts`:

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';

export default function myFunction() {
  const git = simpleGit();
  git.checkout('my-branch');
}
```

`my-module.test.ts`:

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';
import myFunction from './my-module';

jest.mock('simple-git');

const simpleGitMock = simpleGit as jest.Mock

describe('myFunction', () => {
  it('should call checkout with the correct branch', () => {
    const gitMock = {
      checkout: jest.fn(),
    }
    simpleGitMock.mockReturnValue(gitMock)
    myFunction();
    expect(gitMock.checkout).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my-branch');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76176798/my-module.test.ts (18.282 s)
  myFunction
    ✓ should call checkout with the correct branch (6 ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 my-module.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        21.418 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package version:

```json
"simple-git": "^3.18.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working.

``TypeError: simpleGitMock.mockReturnValue is not a function`

`"simple-git": "^3.17.0",`
`"jest": "^29.5.0",`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling on this question, I found my problem was not with my mocking code but instead was with how I was importing simpleGit in my actual code.

The `simple-git` package exports simpleGit as both the default export and as a named export.

From index.d.ts of `simple-git`:

```
export declare const simpleGit: SimpleGitFactory;

export default simpleGit;
```

If you mock simpleGit like this:

```
jest.mock('simple-git');
```

It only works if you import the default export in your code, like this:

```
import simpleGit from "simple-git"
```

Importing the named import (while it works in your code) does not work with the mock:

```
import {simpleGit} from "simple-git";
```